# Extracting elements from lists based on percentage

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list of n sub lists,

```
a =[["cat", "dog", "cow", "apple"], ["apple", "dog"],  ["cat", "apple"]["cat","apple", "deer"]]
```

Assuming that the threshold percentage is 70%, the elements which appear at least 70% of the time in the sub lists should be in the output.
In this example, "apple" appears in all the sub lists, "cat" comes 3/4 time in all the sub lists.
Hence, the output should be ["apple", "cat"]
How can I achieve this?

I was using intersection, but then only the common elements in all sub lists would come in the output.

```
output= list(set(a[0]).intersection(*a))
```

Comment: Could same element appear multiple times in sublist i.e. `cat` appears multiple times in `["cat", "dog", "cow", "apple", "cat"]`?

Comment: No, they are distinct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import collections
import itertools
a =[["cat", "dog", "cow", "apple"], ["apple", "dog"],  ["cat", "apple"],["cat","apple", "deer"]]
n=len(a)
counter = collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*a))
res=[i for i in counter if counter[i]>=0.7*n]
print(res)
```

This prints

```
['cat', 'apple']
```

Comment: The code runs fine, thanks a lot! Although, I am getting this inspection warning in my PyCharm, "Unexpected arugument" for `Counter(itertools.chain(*a))`

Comment: You're welcome! Also, on my PyCharm I don't get any warning, so I guess it depends on the PyCharm version

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for l in a:
...     c.update(set(l))
... 
>>> c
Counter({'apple': 4, 'cat': 3, 'dog': 2, 'deer': 1, 'cow': 1})
>>> [key for key, value in c.items() if value >= 0.7 * len(a)]
['cat', 'apple']
```